# How to escape this string to use variable?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, string

I have a string I would like to escape to insert variable.  Cannot successfully escape the string.

```
'<a href="/'+result.Id+'" id="'+result.Id+'" position="relative" onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('+result.Id+', '/'+result[i].Id+'/m?retURL=%2Fresult.Id&isAjaxRequest=1').show();" target="_blank">'+result.Name+'</a>';
```

This is only part of the string but I can't seem to escape the string in the second parameter of the getHover attribute.

Comment: where you wan't to escape it? In JS, Apex or somewhere else?

Comment: I want to escape it in Javascript.

Comment: @Ashwani, I thought the escape character is same in both JS & Apex - the backward slash character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to understand how it is escaped. Perhaps you may not get such help from here always.

```
alert(
'<a href="'+result.Id+
'" id="'+result.Id+
'" position="relative" onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover(\''+result.Id+
'\', \''+result[i].Id+
'/m?retURL=%2Fresult.Id&isAjaxRequest=1\').show();" target="_blank">'+
result.Name+
'</a>;"'
);
```